# Micronaut - Error encoding object to JSON: No serializer found for class io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Using Micronaut `micronautVersion=3.4.3` getting an below exception for the below code

```
@Validated
public interface ICategoryOperation {
    @Get(value = "/{?searchCriteria*}")
    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
    Flux<?> get(CategoryFilterModel searchCriteria);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller("/api/${api.version:v1}/category")
@Version("1")
public class ApiGatewayCategoryController implements ICategoryOperation {
    private final ICategoryClient iCategoryClient;

    public ApiGatewayCategoryController(ICategoryClient iCategoryClient) {
        this.iCategoryClient = iCategoryClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<?> get(CategoryFilterModel searchCriteria) {
        return this.iCategoryClient.get(searchCriteria);
    }
}
```

**HttpClient**

```
@Client(id="fetebirdProductPublisher", path = "/category")
public interface ICategoryClient  extends ICategoryOperation {
}
```

**CURL**

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/category?total=0&currentPage=0&totalPage=0&pageSize=0&lastId=string&id=string&name=string&description=string' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

**Exception**

```
io.micronaut.http.codec.CodecException: Error encoding object [500 Internal Server Error] to JSON: No serializer found for class io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: io.micronaut.http.netty.NettyMutableHttpResponse["serverCookieEncoder"])
    at io.micronaut.json.codec.MapperMediaTypeCodec.encode(MapperMediaTypeCodec.java:220)
    at io.micronaut.json.codec.MapperMediaTypeCodec.encode(MapperMediaTypeCodec.java:268)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$mapToHttpContent$7(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1047)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onSubscribe(ReactorSubscriber.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onError(ReactorSubscriber.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onError(ReactorSubscriber.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxError.subscribe(FluxError.java:43)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onError(ReactorSubscriber.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:842)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:451)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onError(ReactorSubscriber.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onError(ReactorSubscriber.java:64)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnError(Publishers.java:257)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onError(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:63)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnNext(Publishers.java:250)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onNext(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:165)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:894)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:997)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$1.doOnComplete(Publishers.java:262)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onComplete(StrictSubscriber.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMap$SwitchMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxSwitchMap.java:395)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMap$SwitchMapMain.drain(FluxSwitchMap.java:338)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMap$SwitchMapMain.innerComplete(FluxSwitchMap.java:433)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMap$SwitchMapInner.onComplete(FluxSwitchMap.java:522)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:146)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTimeout.java:234)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:68)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.filters.ClientServerRequestTracingPublisher$1.onComplete(ClientServerRequestTracingPublisher.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onComplete(StrictSubscriber.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onComplete(ReactorSubscriber.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:439)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drainLoop(FluxCreate.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:206)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:197)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$11.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2475)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$11.channelReadInstrumented(DefaultHttpClient.java:2389)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$SimpleChannelInboundHandlerInstrumented.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:3145)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:215)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:180)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ServerCookieEncoder and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: io.micronaut.http.netty.NettyMutableHttpResponse["serverCookieEncoder"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4568)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:3780)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper.writeValue(JacksonDatabindMapper.java:124)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.databind.JacksonDatabindMapper.writeValue(JacksonDatabindMapper.java:129)
    at io.micronaut.json.codec.MapperMediaTypeCodec.encode(MapperMediaTypeCodec.java:218)
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

**dependency**

```
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor:1.0.1")
```

Then as per the documentation, I have enable external serialization in application class as below

```
@SerdeImport(HttpVersion.class)
@SerdeImport(NettyMutableHttpResponse.class)
public class ApiGateway {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(ApiGateway.class, args);
    }
}
```

Still this exception occurs

```
Caused by: io.micronaut.core.beans.exceptions.IntrospectionException: No serializable introspection present for type HttpVersion nettyHttpVersion. Consider adding Serdeable. Serializable annotate to type HttpVersion nettyHttpVersion. Alternatively if you are not in control of the project's source code, you can use @SerdeImport(HttpVersion.class) to enable serialization of this type.
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.DefaultSerdeIntrospections.getSerializableIntrospection(DefaultSerdeIntrospections.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.SerBean.<init>(SerBean.java:96)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.ObjectSerializer.create(ObjectSerializer.java:184)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.ObjectSerializer.lambda$getSerBean$0(ObjectSerializer.java:175)
    at io.micronaut.core.util.SupplierUtil$1.initialize(SupplierUtil.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.core.util.SupplierUtil$1.get(SupplierUtil.java:43)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.ObjectSerializer.createSpecific(ObjectSerializer.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.SerBean.findSerializer(SerBean.java:336)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.SerBean.initProperty(SerBean.java:296)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.SerBean.lambda$new$15(SerBean.java:241)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.SerBean.initialize(SerBean.java:283)
    at io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.CustomizedObjectSerializer.serialize(CustomizedObjectSerializer.java:56)
    ... 126 common frames omitted
```